# Construct a Taylor Polynomial of a function containing an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I am trying to create a taylor polynomial (degree 5)
of

$(1/x)\int_{0}^{x}e^{-v^{2}} dv$

Now I've created taylor polynomials before, but I've never seen a problem involving two variables.

Comment: To respond to your edit: **yes**, your idea works. The only way it could plausibly fail is if your function $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}} dt$ had a constant term, which it does not, because it is $0$ when $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$$
then 
$$f'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} = \frac{-f(x)}{x}+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}.$$
This will give you a recurrence relation to generate successive derivatives with which you could construct your polynomial.

Or something even better, you could change variables and write 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$$
as $(t= xu)$
$$f(x)= \int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2u^2}du = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\frac{(xu)^{2k}}{k!}du\\ 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k}}{(2k+1)k!}.$$

Comment: how did you get f'(x)? im  having trouble seeing how the derivative works out

Comment: You apply the product rule with functions $1/x$ and $\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$ which is also a function of $x.$

Comment: You could use the second trick, if you are not comfortable with the Fundamental Theorem of Caclulus (used to differentiate the integral).

Answer (score 1):

$$e^t=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$$
$$e^{-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(t)^{2n}}{n!}$$
$$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$$
so
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)n!}$$

Comment: @e-h-e where does the 2n+1 come from?

Comment: $\int x^{2n}dx=\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$